# Several COUNTs with conditions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count

I'm currently working on a hit counter with some other statistics, like percentage of the visitors being logged in and so forth.

I've tried many different SQL queries so far, but currently I'm stuck with this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalhits,
COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS visitors,
COUNT(user_id > 0) AS hitsloggedin,
COUNT(DISTINCT ip, user_id > 0) AS visitorsloggedin
FROM db.tblhits
```

Apparently this is wrong. I'm getting all rows counted in the third and fourth COUNT statement although there are rows where user_id is 0. The two first statements works just fine, though.

I'm sure someone is laughing his ass off now, but this is what I've tried with.

Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the logic behind the 4th count?

Comment: Counting the number of distinct ip's where user_id is greater than 0. Don't ask me, I have no idea how I could expect what I tried to work, but you have to start somewhere. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented under [`COUNT(expr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count):

> Returns a count of the number of non-`NULL` values of ***`expr`*** in the rows retrieved by a [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) statement.

Where in your third case ***`expr`*** is `user_id > 0`, it is non-`NULL` when that expression evaluates to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`; and therefore the result of `COUNT()` is not what you expect.

Since MySQL does not have true boolean types, but instead uses `1` and `0` for `TRUE` and `FALSE` respectively, you can simply use [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) instead; in other RDBMS, you'd have to use a [`CASE` expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case):

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN user_id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
```

For your fourth expression, you could do:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN user_id > 0 THEN ip ELSE NULL END)
```

Comment: I used SUM() for the third COUNT statement and after trying out your suggestion for the fourth statement that's what I'm sticking with. Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
SELECT 

(Select COUNT(*) FROM db.tblhits )AS totalhits,
(select COUNT(DISTINCT ip) FROM db.tblhits) AS visitors,
(select COUNT(user_id) FROM db.tblhits where user_id>0) AS hitsloggedin,
(select COUNT(DISTINCT ip ) FROM db.tblhits where user_id > 0) AS visitorsloggedin
FROM db.tblhits
```

Comment: Ouch.  Expensive.  And will also return the result once for every record in `db.tblhits`.  -1

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, although I used SUM for the third COUNT statement, as per juergen d's suggestion.

 `SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalhits,
 COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS visitors,
 SUM(user_id > 0) AS hitsloggedin,
 (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip)
  FROM db.tblhits
  WHERE user_id > 0
 ) AS visitorsloggedin
 FROM db.tblhits`